Can the set of integers be constructed starting from Peano's Axioms without powersets?
I was able to formally construct the set of integers starting from Peano's Axioms using a powerset axiom among other ZF-like axioms (31 lines available here on request).
Informally, I have:
$\pm 0 = \{(0,~ 0),~ (1,~ 1),~ (2, 2), \cdots \}$
$+1 = \{(1,~ 0),~ (2,~ 1),~ (3, 2), \cdots \}$
$-1 = \{(0,~ 1),~ (1,~ 2),~ (2, 3), \cdots \}$
$+2 = \{(2,~ 0),~ (3,~ 1),~ (4, 2), \cdots \}$
$-2 = \{(0,~ 2),~ (1,~ 3),~ (2, 4), \cdots \}$
$~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\vdots$
I understand that, in some circles, the ZF powerset axiom is considered to be controversial.
Q: Is it possible to formally construct the set of integers starting from Peano's Axioms using the ZF-axioms without powersets?

What do you mean when you say you "started from Peano's axioms" but then go on to talk about the powerset axiom?
The Peano axioms are an axiomatisation of the naturals. The ZFC (everything I'm about to say also holds true of ZF if you really want) axioms are an axiomatisation of sets. Although every model of ZFC contains a model of the Peano axioms by the axiom of infinity, there is nothing saying our models of Peano axioms should be sets (by which I mean formal sets, rather than sets in the metalanguage).
Are you saying you constructed a model of the Peano axioms in ZFC?

@AntonyTheo. I start my proof by introducing the usual Peano Axioms in the language of a set theory  loosely base on ZFC. Not every one of these axioms is used in the proof. Then I construct $N\times N$. Then the power set $P(N\times N)$. Then I construct two subsets of this set corresponding to the non-negative integers and the non-positive integer, the integer $\pm 0$ being common to both. Finally I take the pairwise union of both to obtain the set of all integers.

My proof (36 lines): https://www.dcproof.com/ConstructIntegers.htm

Yes it is possible. To construct the integers, all you really need is the existence of $\mathbb{N}$, the existence of Cartesian products, and a little bit of comprehension. Cartesian products are sometimes constructed with power sets, but they can also be built with replacement. You might be worried about the quotienting out by an equivalence relation part, but you can get around this by either representing an integer by a fraction in some canonical form or by showing that ZF without power set can still build the set of those equivalence classes (which it can by replacement). Either way everything goes through more or less as directly as normally.

Have you heard of the Axiom of Infinity? That pretty much directly gives you the natural numbers.
The integers can be constructed from the natural numbers as pairs of natural numbers modulo an equivalence relation. Quotients by equivalence relations can be done without power set if you define the quotient set to be a subset of the original set.
So all this seems very unproblematic to me. Integers do not require power sets. They only require the Axiom of Infinity.

As you can see in my informal examples, I have essentially constructed an equivalence relation for $\pm 0, +1, -1, +2$ and $-2$. I suspect that powersets may be used in the development of the  machinery  for constructing all equivalence relations. Will look into it. Thanks.

It seems to me that a formal development of equivalence relations will require powersets. A link to my formal proof (132 lines), which uses a set theory loosely based on ZFC, is available on request.

There, for an arbitrary set X, I construct the set of all equivalence relations on that set. I also show that the identity relation on X is an element of that set. I think you have to formally prove the existence of equivalence relations, not just assume that one exists.

Yes, it is possible to construct a model of the integers within the pure Peano axiomatic system.
One approach would be to encode members of $\mathbb{Z}$ as natural numbers via the standard bijection
\begin{align*}
0 & \leftrightarrow 0 \\
1 & \leftrightarrow 1 \\
-1 & \leftrightarrow 2 \\
2 & \leftrightarrow 3 \\
-2 & \leftrightarrow 4 \\
& \vdots \\
n & \leftrightarrow (2n-1), n > 0 \\
-n & \leftrightarrow (2n), n > 0.
\end{align*}
It is then possible to define the transports of addition, unary negation, and multiplication in $\mathbb{Z}$ as functions $+_{\mathbb{Z}}, -_{\mathbb{Z}}, \cdot_{\mathbb{Z}}$ operating on the natural numbers using (strong) recursion.  As a starting example, $-_{\mathbb{Z}}$ would be the function $0 \mapsto 0, 1 \mapsto 2, 2 \mapsto 1, 3 \mapsto 4, 4 \mapsto 3, \ldots$.
However, this does have the disadvantage that the definitions will involve several cases, and proving theorems such as the associativity of $+_{\mathbb{Z}}$ will involve even more cases.
Another approach would be to observe that each equivalence class in your definition has a unique element where one of the coordinates is zero.  Furthermore, you can construct a reduction function via strong recursion which maps each $(m, n) = \binom{m+n+1}{2} + n$ to the unique such representative.  So in this approach, you can specify that the model will be the set (in the second-order logic sense) of natural numbers of the form $(n, 0) = \binom{n+1}{2}$ or $(0, n) = \binom{n+1}{2}+n$, and for example, addition is the restriction of the function which sends $((m, n), (m', n'))$ to the reduction of $(m+m', n+n')$.  Then for example to prove associativity of addition, you observe that $$((m, n) +_{\mathbb{Z}} (m', n')) +_{\mathbb{Z}} (m'', n'') \sim (m+m'+m'', n+n'+n'')\\ \sim (m,n) +_{\mathbb{Z}} ((m',n') +_{\mathbb{Z}} (m'',n'')),$$ and both sides are reduced, so by the uniqueness of the reduced element of an equivalence class, both sides are equal.
Note that the above assumes we're working in second-order Peano arithmetic.  In fact, each can also be adapted to work in pure first-order Peano arithmetic, i.e. where the induction principle is not a second-order axiom, but a first-order axiom schema.  In that case, in place of unary and binary functions, we will need to substitute first-order propositional formulas with respectively two or three free variables which can be proven to act like a function.  Also, in order to construct these formulas based on the recursive definitions, we will need to make use of the first-order recursion metatheorem.  Furthermore, in the second case, in place of the subset $\{ (n, 0) \} \cup \{ (0, n) \}$, we will need to use a first-order propositional formula with one free variable.  In this case, what we end up with is not a "model" in the strict sense of model theory, but something closely related.  In particular, it would provide a way to take any proof in the first-order language of $(\mathbb{Z}, +, -, \cdot)$ and translate it into a proof in first-order Peano arithmetic.

Let $\mathbb{N}=\{1,2,...\}$, $0=\emptyset$ and for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$ define $-n = \left(0,n\right)$. Therefore $n+\left(0,n\right)=0$ by definition. I think it's possible to extend usual addition and multiplication on ℕ to the full operations on $\mathbb{Z}=\mathbb{N}\cup\{\emptyset\}\cup\left(\{\emptyset\}\times\mathbb{N}\right)$
